# Erro de conversão de dados

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, conversão-de-tipo

Não consigo abrir meu formulário de controle de usuários.

```
private void usuáriosToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Usuarios USU = new Usuarios();
        sNome_usu = Status_Label_Usuario.Text;
        USU.iAcesso_Usuario = Convert.ToInt16(Status_Label_Tipo);
        USU.Show();
    }
```

o erro é o seguinte :[image: SS]

Comment: clique em View Detali.... e posto o erro mais detalhado.

Comment: Presta atenção nessa linha: `Convert.ToInt16(Status_Label_Tipo);`. O que é o `Status_Label_Tipo`? se for um controle, como um textbox ou um label, por exemplo, o certo seria utilizar `Status_Label_Tipo.Text`. Fazendo isso acredito que resolva

Comment: @RennanHanna passa seu aspx com o tipo do seu controle `Status_Label_Tipo` e como vc esta carregando ele no seu code behind, assim vai facilitar na resposta da sua pergunta.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 1):

Pode ter alguns problemas:

```
USU.iAcesso_Usuario = Convert.ToInt16(Status_Label_Tipo);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conversion/ToShort.cs).

Possivelmente deveria pegar `Status_Label_Tipo.Text`.

Dependendo do tipo de `USU.iAcesso_Usuario` talvez a conversão precisa ser mudada, mas não dá para dizer com tão poucas informações.

Tenho minhas dúvidas se só colocando esta informação é suficiente para mostrar o usuário e estar apto para mostrar o formulário. De novo, não dá para saber com tão poucas informações.

Comment: A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: A cadeia de caracteres de entrada não estava em um formato incorreto.

Comment: apareceu este erro Bigown

Comment: Como eu disse, tem poucas informações, então é complicado ajudar mais que isto. Talvez nem deveria estar fazendo o que está tentando. Mas não dá para saber sem conhecer os detalhes do problema.

Comment: Tenho um banco de dados com 3 tabelas: nome senha e acesso

Comment: quais informações precisa para tentar me ajudar?